# What is wrong with this PHP static Method?

Tags: php, static, static-methods

I have declared a static method in class `category`

```
public static function getPrefixFromSubCategoyId($subCategoryId) {
    $prefix = $this->fetch(array('table' => 'subCategories', 'id' => $subCategoryId));
    return $prefix[0]['prefix'];
}
```

i am sure that i am using correct piece of code because when i use the same code outside the class scope with following code it works properly

```
$category = new Category($dbh);
$subCategoryId = 6;
$prefix = $category->fetch(array('table' => 'subCategories', 'id' => $subCategoryId));
echo $prefix[0]['prefix'];
```

but when i initialize the static method with following syntax.

```
$prefix = Category::getPrefixFromSubCategoyId(4);
```

it gives me following error.

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

am i missing something? or am i declaring it the wrong way?

thank you..

Comment: Well, it says you're using `$this` in a static method, which you are, and isn't allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

static methods are class members and aren't bound to an object. This means, that `$this` simply doesn't exists. You cannot use it in static methods. If `fetch()` is static too, call it static

```
self::fetch(/* arguments */);
```

If not either `getPrefixFromSubCategoyId()` should not be static too, `fetch()` should be static (see example above), or you need an object

```
$tmp = new self;
$tmp->fetch(/* arguments */);
```

Comment: You cannot call `non-static function` under `static function`, `static` methods are initialized once you use your class but `not-static functions` are initialized once you use `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

$this is a reference to the current object. It is not the reference to the class. Since you are using it statically you have no object. You would have to make a static call in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is used to get instance variables or methods (simple members and basically the current object if you have one defining with `new`) but when you want to reach the static variables you should use `$self::some_varible` and `::` is scope resolution operator.

You must declare your methods or variables `static` if you do want to use them under a `static function`.